# Random URLs return error code 500 instead of 404

Tags: django, error-handling, http-status-code-404

In my `urls.py` file, I've got the following :

```
def error_404(request): return render(request, 'shop/errors/404.html')
def error_500(request): return render(request, 'shop/errors/500.html')

handler404 = error_404
handler500 = error_500
```

However, when I enter random urls, like "mysite.com/lhazeglazd", a 500 error page is returned.

What is causing 500 errors from overriding my 404 errors ?

Answer (score 1):

Your logs or the admin error email should give the reason for the 500 server error.

Note that you don’t need custom 404 and 500 handlers in this case. The default handlers look for `404.html` and `500.html` by default, so you just need to move your templates up a couple of directories.

If you must have a custom 500 handler, note that it’s not recommended to pass the request to render - if there’s a problem with a context processor the error will reoccur when trying to render the 500 template.

Comment: You were right ! I removed the handlers and placed my `404.html` and `500.html` directly in `projectname/static/templates`, and things are working properly now !